# Comparing the return values of methods with multiple return values

Tags: go

Considering the following example methods, each of which returns three integers:

```
func a() (int, int, int) {...}

func b() (int, int, int) {...}
```

I want to know if the return values of these methods are the same, something like this:

```
equal := a() == b()
```

However, this doesn't compile because the compiler is expecting a single value:

```
my_file.go:14: multiple-value a() in single-value context
my_file.go:14: multiple-value b() in single-value context
```

---

My current work around is to create a custom type with the same signature as the methods, and then create a third function to do the checking:

```
type multiReturnFunc func() (int, int, int)
func a() (int, int, int) {...}
func b() (int, int, int) {...}

func checkMultiReturns(a, b multiReturnFunc) bool {
    a1, a2, a3 := a()
    b1, b2, b3 := b()
    return a1 == b1 && a2 == b2 && a3 == b3
}

...

equal := checkMultiReturns(a, b)
```

But I would like to have a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you want, but if instead of returning three unnamed ints you return structs, you can compare them directly. E.g.

```
type XYZ struct{ X, Y, Z int }

func f() XYZ { return XYZ{1, 2, 3} }
func g() XYZ { return XYZ{1, 2, 3} }

func main() {
    fmt.Println(f() == g())
    // Output:
    //   true
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/zFXPqPjTtZ.

Answer (score 1):

#### With structs

You can slightly improve it by storing the result in values of a struct which are comparable:

```
type Result struct {
    a, b, c int
}
```

And using it:

```
p, q := Result{}, Result{}
p.a, p.b, p.c = a()
q.a, q.b, q.c = b()
fmt.Println(p == q)
```

#### With arrays

Or you can use arrays (arrays are also comparable unlike slices), although this won't be shorter, but you don't need a new type for this:

```
x, y := [3]int{}, [3]int{}
x[0], x[1], x[2] = a()
y[0], y[1], y[2] = b()
fmt.Println(x == y)
```

#### General solution (using `reflect`)

A general solution may be constructed using the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package. This basically calls both functions, and compares all the result values. Error checks omitted!

```
func check(v1, v2 reflect.Value) bool {
    r1 := v1.Call(nil)
    r2 := v2.Call(nil)
    if len(r1) != len(r2) {
        return false
    }

    for i, a := range r1 {
        if a.Interface() != r2[i].Interface() {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

And using it:

```
fmt.Println(check(reflect.ValueOf(a), reflect.ValueOf(b)))
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/iHmnwiNrIq).